# Simplicity of kernel of the evaluation map of stable sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $F$ be a stable torsion free sheaves on a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $F$ is generated by global sections, i.e. the evaluation map $ev: H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\to F$ is surjective. Let $K$ be the kernel sheaf of $ev$.

My question is: Is $K$ a simple sheaf, i.e. $Hom(K,K)=\mathbb{C}$?

If we assume $F$ is not generated by global sections, and consider the cone $C$ of map $ev: H^0(F)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\to F$. Do we also have $Hom(C,C)=\mathbb{C}$? Here $Hom(C,C)$ is taken in the category of bounded complex of $Coh(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For instance, let $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ and $F = T$, the tangent bundle. Then $F$ is globally generated but it is easy to see that the kernel of the evaluation morphism is isomorphic to $\Omega(1)^{\oplus 3}$, hence is not simple.

Comment: Dear Sasha, thank for your answering!  Actually in my situation $h^0(F)=3$ and $F$ is a stable vector bundle of rank $2$. Will the kernel (or the cone) be simple under these assumptions?

Comment: In this case the kernel is a line bundle, hence simple (if $X$ is connected).